# SQL Server 2008 : error 5 - Invalid Parameter(s) found

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, express

I've been trying to figure out this issue for hours now.

I have 3 stations on the same network, all in which can talk to each other (I have folders shared on each computer that the others can access). The main station where the database is being held works with no problem. I can wrong the program and it can access the database, I can make changes etc.

Now when I attempt to connect the other stations to the master, I get an error:

> Provider: Named pipes Provider, error. 5 - Invalid Parameter(s) found.

The following things are what I have done:

- disabled firewall
- shared SQL folder along with giving "everyone" full control
- "everyone" has full access to the `Data` and `Log` folder
- enabled the shared memory, named and TCP/IP pipes in Server Config Manager
- I have a password for SA and I am using it to connect to the DB
- `DBConfigurator` can connect to the DB from Station 2 (child) to Station 1 (master) with no issues but fails and ask for database settings when I open the program

Sorry if this is a little confusing but I don't know where else to go.

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) It's probably not a good idea to share the server's `SQL` folder, much less giving "everyone" full control; 2) Only SQL Server needs access to the `Data` and `Log` folders.  The SQL Server database engine stores the files that compose the databases and their transaction logs in those folders and they should only be accessed by SQL Server; 3) You don't say, but if your workstations are in a common AD domain, you should consider using Windows AD accounts for access to SQL Server rather than SQL Server accounts; 4) Your final comment is confusing. Please elaborate.

Comment: Show us your connection string

Comment: Since it's named pipes to provide an error, I guess you pass \\fileshare instead of instance name

Comment: Thank you for the help, I can't work on this site tell Wednesday